# packing bits into an integer in C++

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I want to pack the lowest two bytes of an integer into another in integer, an stuck at this

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 8 ; i ++){
         if ((bitmask & ( 1 << i)))
             result |= 1 >> i;
     }
```

Comment: `x = (y & 0xFFFF) + (x & ~0xFFFF);` ?

Comment: @Borgleader lowest 2 bytes, not lowest 2 bits

Comment: @PeterT Oh misread that. In my defense though, the idea is the same, only the mask changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Endian-independent solution:

```
x = ((y >> 0) & 0xFF) |
    ((y >> 8) & 0xFF);
```

Comment: Why?  He's working with integral types in both cases, so there can be no endian issues.

Comment: @JamesKanze I just meant that some other solution like `uint8_t* ptr = (uint8_t*)&the_int; x = *ptr; ptr++; x |= *ptr;` would be endian-dependant, because then you don't know if `ptr` would give you the ms byte or the ls byte. Same issue if you solve the problem by making a union out of 1 uint32_t and 4 uint8_t.

Comment: @Lundin Endian-independent solution for what exactly?  All I see is the lowest two bytes of y smooshed together and assigned to x.

Comment: @Orwellophile As in, the endianess of `y` doesn't matter. Unlike solutions using pointer arithmetic or unions etc.

Comment: @Lundin True, endianess won't affect the result, but that's because your self has smooshed the two lowest bytes into one byte using a bitwise or.  It's also not doing anything helpful or even reversible (in any endian format).

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you correctly sufficient solution should be this:

```
another_integer = first_integer & 0xFFFF // which is 65536, which is 2^16 so 0000000011111111 binary (for 4 byte integer)
```

That way you would assign value of two lower bytes of first_integer to the another_integer by using simple AND mask:

```
0101110011101010
0000000011111111 AND
----------------
0000000011101010
```

Comment: Yeah, decimal numbers are harder to read bits out of. if I see `0xF0F0` then I know that there's 4 bits alternating on and off by just looking at it, try that with 61680